Navigate to any module from any module in 6 module multi module android project
I have 6 modules each module is kind of different app but i make 5 module as a library module and 6th module as the application module to launch activity and other
all module work on one activity and other fragment architecture
Now i want to go from any module activity to any other module activity like if i have 6 modules A,B,C,D,E,F  i want to go from A to other five activity only same for B to other five activities.
I only need to switch to each module main activities nothing else.
But the problem is circular dependency and without including modules in each module i am not getting their activity import
I try various methods from explicit, implicit intents.
trying making a 7th common module and include all module dependency their and then include that only in each but still same circular dependency.
Hours of discussion to gpt 4 and gemini AI
I am using kotlin and build.gradle.kts, AGP = 8.1.4, Gradle version = 8.2

The seventh module approach seems your best bet, but you might need an 8th module.
Make a seventh module with an interface which all 6 activities must implement.
The 6 modules than depend on the 7th module and not on each other.
The 8th module is for dependency injection. This module depends on all 7 modules and injects in one module the activities of the five other modules.
You can find a description of the structure here. I am sure you can adapt the idea to your application.
